# Input from form, GAE, wrong

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode

By some reason, I am getting strange input for Cyrillic symbols in GAE.

In local environment all works fine, I get what was in input field, with `self.request.get('')`.
But on Appspot, I get "1mxt1czq0snfzq==" or "0ylqtdgb0yi=" for example, instead of Russian words.

in .py

```
!/usr/bin/env python
-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
title = self.request.get('title')
```

in .html

```
meta charset="utf-8"
input type="text" name="title" id="title"
```

I'm stuck.

**EDIT:**
Yes, it is Base64, you are right. But why is GAE using it? And where to change it? Why the different behavior in local and in Appspot?

In same form I'm trying to get the file to BlobHandler

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ upload_url }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="title">Title</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="file">Load image</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept='image/*' required="required">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**EDIT2:**
Yes.
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2749

Seems like a bug in GAE with BlobHandler.

Solution: **accept-charset="utf-8"** in form, trying that later.

Comment: That looks like `base64` encoded data...

Answer (score 2):

**Bug**: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2749

accept-charset="utf-8" in form dont work.

**Solution**: 
in app.yaml add library

```
- name: webob
  version: "1.2.3"
```

Comment: Solution, as i see. Using latest version of library with bug fix.